# How to dispatch a block with parameter on main queue or thread

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

Blocks are awesome. Because I thought I understood them, I wanted to up the ante and use them in a little more complex situation. Now these blocks are kicking me in the face, and I'm trying to break it down into comprehensible pieces.

Say I have two blocks in this pseudo code conveniently named `blockA` and `blockB`. The first is a simple parameter-less block and it just prints a line. The second takes one parameter `xyz` of type `id`:

```
void (^blockA){ NSLog(@"Doing something"); };
void (^blockB)(id xyz){ [xyz doSomething]; };
```

When running `blockA`, I would do something like `blockA();` or when I want to target the main queue/thread, I use the `dispatch_sync` or `_async` method:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blockA);
```

But although I know how to dispatch `blockB` with a parameter like `blockB(someObject);`, I can't figure out how to explicitly call that one on the main thread. I was looking for something like the next line, but of course that's *not* how this works:

<s>dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue, blockB, someObject);</s>

Now I've tried wrapping the block in another block, but to be honest that just doesn't look right and it felt like it was causing more problems than it solved. Is there something other than wrapping blocks to dispatch one block with one or more parameters on the main queue/thread?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope. Wrapping blocks is exactly what you have to do in this case. In code:

```
void (^block)(id someArg) = someBlock;
id object = someObject;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    block(someObject);
});
```

It may look a little strange at first, but this style makes the dispatch APIs so much simpler and the automatic retaining of captured variables makes it possible. I'm a little surprised you ran into problems. What were they?

Comment: I'm getting a dreadful web lock crash, which I can't trace back to its origin: *Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...* That's why I'm breaking the issue down, because any code running at that point should have been running on the main thread. I thought nesting the blocks might have been causing this, but from what you say it looks like it's something else.

Comment: What's the difference of just using the object in the block?, and I think what you meant to define is `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ block(object);});`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting used to blocks too. Honestly I can't see anything cleaner/better than:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{blockb(someObj);});
```